# Entry to back-side of power curve

Tags: flight-dynamics, slow-flight

When entering slow flight, when do we enter the back side of the power curve? Is it when we reduce the throttle or when the airspeed decreases to just above 5 knots from the stall speed?

Answer (score 2):

In a piston engine propeller powered aircraft, you're on the back side of the power curve when you are flying at lower than the speed for minimum power.

[image: Power curve]

By definition, the power required to maintain steady level flight increases from this point whether we increase or decrease airspeed.  The important part here is that the power curve has a positive slope to the right (increasing airspeed) and a negative slope to the left (decreasing airspeed).

At speeds greater than minimum power required, the positive slope of power vs. velocity means that it takes more power to fly faster (this is normal).

At speeds slower than minimum power required, the negative slope of power vs. velocity means that it takes less power to fly faster (this is the back side of the power curve).